# Angular testing a component with Jasmine in a multi module file project

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've been trying to get this to work,the service tests that only depended on the httpclient worked fine. Yet when I try to test a component with some dependencies like this (I don't even need to put the test itself for the errors to show):

```
describe('test suite name', () => {
 let component: ExampleComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
 let testBed;

 let dependencyMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Dependency', ['action']);

 beforeEach(async () => {
  testBed = await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ExampleComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: Dependency, useValue: dependencyMock }
  ],
  imports: [
    // FormsModule,
    // MatDialogModule,
    // BrowserModule,
    // BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
 }).compileComponents();
});

});
```

A multitude of errors show up in the console with nearly all of them being of this type:

```
app/someRandomLocation/RandomFile.component.ts:7:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/someOtherRandomLocation/AnotherRandomFile.ts'.

7 import { AnotherRandomFile } from 'src/app/someOtherRandomLocation/AnotherRandomFile';
```

I've tried to put AppModule in the imports to check if it solved the problem, it just gave me more errors.

This is a project where there are multiple *Module files to separate them a bit.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

Surprisingly, after changing the path in the example import from this:

```
import { AnotherRandomFile } from 'src/app/someOtherRandomLocation/AnotherRandomFile';
```

To this:

```
import { AnotherRandomFile } from '../app/someOtherRandomLocation/AnotherRandomFile';
```

Said errors do disappear, although these would not be an acceptable solution for this project. My other projects did not have the same problem, does anyone know a solution that does not require changing all the imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone finds themselves in the same predicament, the solution to the problem was:

- Go to the file tsconfig.spec.json
- Either comment out (fixed it for me) or change the baseUrl property so it fits your project